# Inject this field value directly into "studentStepOne", the only method that uses it

Tags: java, sonarqube, spring-batch

I've developed **Spring Boot-Batch** code and `sonarlint/Sonar-Qube` giving me below error. I went through the link, but solution is not understood as per this link: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/spring/RSPEC-3305.

> Inject this field value directly into "studentStepOne", the only method that uses it.

**Code:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class StudentJob {
    @Value( "${spring.chunk.size}")
    private String chunkSize;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcCursorItemReader<Student> StudentReader;

    @Autowired
    private ItemProcessor<Student, Student> StudentProcessor;

    @Autowired
    private StudentWriter StudentWriter;

    @Bean
    public StudentStepExecuListner StudentStepExecuListner() {
        return new StudentStepExecuListner();
    }

    @Bean("readStudentJob")
    @Primary
    public Job readStudentJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("readStudentJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(StudentStepOne())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step StudentStepOne() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("StudentStepOne")
                .<Student, Student>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
                .reader(StudentReader)
                .processor(StudentProcessor)
                .writer(StudentWriter)
                .listener(StudentStepExecuListner())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you fixed this issue, Can you please guide me on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the link, it seems self-explanatory:

> That means using parameter injection instead of field injection for
>   dependencies that are only used in a single @Bean method.

So for your job, instantiate it like this:

```
  @Bean("readStudentJob")
  @Primary
  public Job readStudentJob(Step StudentStepOne) {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("readStudentJob")
              .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
              .start(StudentStepOne)
              .build();
  }
```

Unrelated, but you should follow java conventions. Methods should use camelcase. `StudentStepOne()` should be `studentStepOne()`

Comment: Dont you think I should use (@Autowire Step StudentStepOne) otherwise how unique instance will be created ?

Comment: You do not need to explicitly declare `@Autowired` in a bean definition method. It will be autowired automatically.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider How have you fixed this issue, Can you please guide me on it

Comment: Here is an example code to help you:

Noncompliant Code Example:
`@Configuration
public class ​FooConfiguration {

  @Autowired private ​DataSource dataSource​;  // Noncompliant

  @Bean
  public ​MyService myService() {
    return new ​MyService(this​.dataSource​);
  }
}`


Compliant Solution:
`@Configuration
public class ​FooConfiguration {

 @Bean
  public ​MyService myService(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new ​MyService(dataSource);
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

In a *@Configuration* class the spring will read the class trying reference with all existent beans.
So, if you wanna only reference one bean in your method, without share between methods, you don't need wired in a class attribute. Just receive in your method constructor.

```
    @Bean
public Step StudentStepOne(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("StudentStepOne")
            .<Student, Student>chunk(Integer.parseInt(chunkSize))
            .reader(StudentReader)
            .processor(StudentProcessor)
            .writer(StudentWriter)
            .listener(StudentStepExecuListner())
            .build();
}
```

The spring will set the bean automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Below Answer will help you.

```
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public void setStepBuilderFactory(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    this.stepBuilderFactory= stepBuilderFactory;
}
```

Instead of implementing field Injection, You can go through with setter injection. Field Injection is not recommended.